# measure how much a triangle face a light

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, geometry

I have 3 vertices forming a triangle:

```
var a = [0, 0, 0];
var b = [1, 0, 0];
var c = [1, 1, 0];
```

and a light:

```
var d = [0, 1, 1];
```

[image]

How can I compute if the triangle face the light or not, and how much?

Comment: use angle between the light source vector and the vector normal to the plane of the triangle.

Comment: what do you mean 'face the light' (hypotenuse)? what have you tried so far?

Comment: The vertices can be along z, so the triangle can rotate on itself. If the triangle rotate, how can I compute his normal and compute how much he face the light ?

Comment: It really depends what you mean by "facing." One possible definition involves drawing a perpendicular line from the midpoint of AC (call this M) in the same plane as ABC. If D falls on that line, the triangle is facing D; otherwise, you can calculate the angle between DM and the perpendicular line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to calculate the intensity of the point over the whole triangle. Conceptually the code could look like this:

```
var vector1 = Vector(c, a); // a vector from a -> c
var vector2 = Vector(b, a); // a vector from a -> c
var normal = cross(vector1, vector2);

// normalize the vector, i.e length of the normal vector is 1
normal = normalize(normal);

var vectorToLightSource = Vector(lightSourceVector, a); // Any point could be taken. The result would vary some.
vectorToLightSource = normalize(vectorToLightSource);

// This will be a value between -1 and 1, but light can't be negative
var intensity = dotProduct(normal, vectorToLightSource); 
intensity = intensity > 0 ? intensity : 0;
```

Now you could take the color of the triangle to be `color = lightSourceColor*intensity`.

The code above is very pseudo; functions like `cross`,`normalize` etc needs to be constructed. For this I recommend using a geometry library, or if you like linear algebra you could construct them yourself :)

For reference:

`cross`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

`dotProduct`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

`normalize`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector